# How to find out exact root cause exception from a wrapper exception?

Tags: java, exception, checked-exceptions

Lets take this example

```
public MyClass{
    public void myMethod() throws ExceptionC{
        try{
            //some method calll throwing ExceptionA, ExceptionB
        }catch(ExceptionA | ExceptionB e){
            throw new ExceptionC(e);
        }
    }
}
```

So I bubble up any of **ExceptionA** or **ExceptionB** into higher level as **ExceptionC**. So I am going to use myClass.myMethod() as follows.

```
try{
    MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
    myclass.myMethod();
}catch(Exception C){
    //I want to find whether ExceptionC happened from ExceptionA or ExceptionB????
}
```

So as my code comment suggests **//I want to find whether ExceptionC happened from ExceptionA or ExceptionB????**

Can someone please explain, how can I do that?

(Please don't take the famous checked-exceptions-good-or-bad war into  here.)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause--.  You may have to call it more than once.

Comment: @ajb thnx for the reference. And what do you mean by more than once?

Comment: I mean, the exception (or `Throwable`) returned by `getCause()` may itself be a wrapper that has its own `getCause()`.  You'll need to decide whether this is a possibility.  But when I've written unit tests that test an exception's cause, I use a loop, because there are lots of things around our code that can wrap exceptions.

Comment: since your example is "MyClass" i'll assume you own MyClass and would recommend against wrapping the causedBy Exception in the first place unless there's a strong reason for doing so.  While it was worse 10+ years ago when Java didn't even support a "wrapping" Exception in the JDK (and root causes were often lost), don't wrap for the hell of it and avoid the problem you describe altogether